# Merge existing incremental backup with base backup before taking next incremental backup?

Tags: mariadb

i am playing with incremental backups in mariadb (am new to it). So relying on docs here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incremental-backup-and-restore-with-mariabackup/

It says that:

1. take a base backup:
   `mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/mariadb/backup/ --user=mariabackup --password=mypassword`
2. Take an incremental backup based on base:
   `mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/mariadb/inc1/ --incremental-basedir=/var/mariadb/backup/ --user=mariabackup --password=mypassword`
3. Take incremental backup no. 2 based on incremental backup no. 1
   `mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/mariadb/inc2/ --incremental-basedir=/var/mariadb/inc1/ --user=mariabackup --password=mypassword`
4. Create further incremental backups similarly like a chain.

**My question:**

Can I instead take a different approach,
That is: merge the incremental backup no. 1 with the base backup and then take incremental backup 2 over the base backup ?

Something like:

`mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/mariadb/backup/ --user=mariabackup --password=mypassword`

`mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/mariadb/inc1/ --incremental-basedir=/var/mariadb/backup/ --user=mariabackup --password=mypassword`

`mariabackup --prepare --target-dir=/var/mariadb/backup --incremental-dir=/var/mariadb/inc1`

`mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/mariadb/inc2/ --incremental-basedir=/var/mariadb/backup/ --user=mariabackup --password=mypassword`

Is it not possible, if possible any pros/cons ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few [outstanding bugs on incremental backup](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31042?jql=status%20in%20(Open%2C%20Confirmed%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Stalled%2C%20%22In%20Review%22)%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22incremental%20backups%22) so I'd be very cautious of trying to be too innovative here.

What you describe kind of makes sense and looking at the code its the LSN info in `xtrabackup_checkpoints` that is read along with looking for dropped datbases and doing a full copy of non-innodb tables again.

Test very carefully (and please report bugs, even if it just means documentation needs to improve).

Keep enough binary logs from the last prepared backup as a second option in recovery.